# I can't ping my gateway, but I can ssh to a remote server. Why?

Tags: linux, ping

I'm trying to configure my dorm room network.  I'm working on ubuntu.  It seems that the dorm building has a host as gateway `192.168.22.254`.

My `route -n` looks like this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.22.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.22.254  0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
```

I can't ping `192.168.22.254`.

```
$ ping 192.168.22.254
PING 192.168.22.254 (192.168.22.254) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.22.254 icmp_seq=3 Packet filtered
From 192.168.22.254 icmp_seq=5 Packet filtered
From 192.168.22.254 icmp_seq=7 Packet filtered
^C
--- 192.168.22.254 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 6014ms
```

But I can ssh to a school server with an ip like `202.XXX.XXX.XXX`, and gain internet access from that server.

- Is this normal?
- I'm desperate for some basic network knowledge, are there any good books or web resources?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Not normal, but certainly not very unusual.  Many networks don't allow anyone to ping the infrastructure, especially if they service comparitively-untrusted end-users.

A more useful test of whether a host is really available is to try pinging it, and then examine your ARP cache for an entry.  To participate in a layer 2 conversation (which acting as your default gateway on an ethernet network definitely counts as), the host **must** respond to ARP requests, or you can't talk to it.  From your ubuntu host, try

```
arp -a -n|grep 22.254
```

If you see something like

```
? (192.168.22.254) at 00:c0:f0:3b:4d:eb [ether] on eth0
```

then it's up and available, even if it's filtering ICMP echo-requests (ping requests).  If you get

```
? (192.168.22.253) at <incomplete> on eth0
```

then it's genuinely down.

2) The absolute bible is Stevens' "TCP/IP Illustrated", but it's not light reading.  However, by the time you get to the end of the last volume, you'll know a lot!  Others may have recommendations for lighter reading.